# What value of t do I choose for the following Directional Derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Find the directional derivative of

$f\left( x,y,z\right) =x^{2}+yz$

At $\left( 1,3,2)\right)$ in the direction of increasing t along the path :

$r\left( t\right) =t^{2}i+3tj+\left( 1-t^{3}\right)k$

So far I have found the derivative of f and r(t) at the point. But then i am presented with the roblem of which t to choose, this is what is confusing me. How to choose the right value for t ? And if so, what lets me know its the correct value for t ?

Thanks

Comment: It appears that you’ve gotten a sign wrong somewhere in the problem statement. The point (1,3,2) isn’t on the given path, but $(1,-3,2)$ is.

Comment: I've edited it now, was just wondering how you choose your value t , its left me very confused

Comment: You need to choose $t$ so that $r(t)=(1,3,2)$. Unfortunately, even with your edit, there’s no value of $t$ for which this holds. The $3tj$ term requires $t=1$, but that gives $(1-1^3)k=0$.